# Facebook SDK 3.22 (android) - Send message without using messager

Tags: android, facebook

I want my app to send private messages to user's friend. So I've read the official facebook tutorial but I found only examples of sending with the help of the messeger. So I asked myself: "And if the user hasn't got Messager installed? There is no way for him?". Maybe I should use Intent with SEND_ACTION (I saw this constraction somewhere).

So the question: "Is there a way of sending messages without the help of the Messager?" and if there is, could you plese post the example or the link.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to send a message to another user are the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) and the [Message Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog).

If they don´t work without the installed Messenger, there is no other way.

Comment: Send dialog is not supported on mobile devices.